# Sitecore Desktop - Start - All Applications - Run - what all can you do with it?

Tags: sitecore-client

From Sitecore Desktop - Start - All Applications - Run.

The dialog states: "Type the name of a application, folder, document or Internet resource, and Sitecore will open it for you."

However, the only thing I've got to work so far, is entering path to `[[core]/Sitecore/Content/Applications/]` .. by entering for example: `Security/Role Manager` in the popup.

I am just curious as the wording of the dialog stating an "Internet Resource". Can this be used for any other things besides launching Applications?

Answer (score 1):

It really is just for running an application from Sitecore, which is where the `Browse` button links you to.

You *can* put in an external web resource in, like `http://www.startrek.com/images/TNG.jpg` - but out of the box sitecore has the `X-Frame-Options` set to `sameorigin` and so it prevents anything like that loading in the `IFrame`. You will get this error in the browser:

> Refused to display 'http://www.startrek.com/images/TNG.jpg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.